# How to update admin html for Catalog > Manage Products > Edit Product > Images

Tags: php, html, magento, admin, backend

In Magento admin, Catalog -> Manage Products -> Edit product -> Images tab, I'm looking to update the html that is loaded to the right for updating the product images. Specifically, I want to edit the `alt` attribute on the image html tags that are loaded there. I cannot find the html for this. Would anyone mind helping me find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template file is `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like this loads the placeholder html, and the js that loads the image on hover is `js/mage/adminhtml/product.js`

Comment: @SVMRAJESH, accepted answer, how about that? Makes you think twice before leaving such a comment next time, doesn't it? We're all just trying to help here.

Comment: @subroutines Please give some description for your answer instead of giving in one line. The answer must be useful for the person who will refer in future also.

Comment: @SVMRAJESH, I like getting straight to the point instead of leaving some useless comment without even reading OP's question/comments carefully like some people do. Just because it's one line doesn't mean its not useful for a question like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't do that.

Your attribute "alt" doesn't set by there. Each case is on case, you should look for "phtml" who render that image and see how / where it catch the "alt" attribute.

All times i've saw that, it's the product name.

You can change it by do your own phtml.

Edit: I recommend you to use "template hints" to find exactlly witch phtml you should use.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the file (.phtml most likely) that generates these `<img` html tags. Do you know where I can find it?